# Cannot use splice with NodeList returned by querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, nodelist

I am getting a NodeList (which is essentially an Array-like Object) using querySelectorAll as follows:

```
var elements = document.getElementById('something').querySelectorAll('.lazy');
```

Then, I try to delete one item from this NodeList using `splice`:

```
elements.splice(0, 1);
```

And I get the following error:

```
elements.splice is not a function.
```

How can I remove the element from the NodeList? Alternatively, should I store each element of the NodeList in an array and use splice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NodeList` is not an `Array` or a subtype of it, so it wont have access to `Array.prototype.splice`.

If you want to use `splice`, you can convert it to an Array first:

`var elementArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(elements);`

Edit: Sorry, got splice and slice mixed up.

Comment: I am getting an error: TypeError: Cannot set property length of #<NodeList> which has only a getter

Comment: Got `splice` and `slice` mixed up.  You can pass a NodeList to slice, not splice.